# Sendconnector for each Exchange a exklusive smarthosts?

Tags: exchange

I have an Exchange 2016 and installed a new Exchange 2019 (both mailbox role) next to it. 
Both work like expected, send and receive via smarthost.
So far all mailboxdatabases (except testing DBs) are located on the 2016 one.

Now I want to add a new smarthost and let it route mail in dependency of the mailbox database. 
Of course there is no built in sender based routing, so I thought to create a second send connector and define as source server the new 2019 Exchange.

So it would look like this: 
exchange2016 --> smarthost1 --> internet 
exchange2019 --> smarthost2 --> internet

Can the sendconnector option source server be used for my plan?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Exchange route messages based on recipients, not the senders, so I think it doesn’t need to create send connector in dependency of the mailbox database. Send connector is an organization level item, all servers could visit it, you could add different servers as source server property.
Here is a reference about [connector selection in mail routing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-routing/connector-selection?view=exchserver-2019).

Comment: Yes you are right. There is an option called "source server". I thought I can set for each exchange such a connector and set it on the "source server".

Comment: Yes, you could just have a try. It is better to do a test before apply to product environment.